# how to only show future appointments in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to design a health appointment manager. I am trying to only show future appointments in the index blade, but also have a button which i can click on to  see past appointments. What I´ve encountered is that in the index blade, both past and future appointments are shown. When i click on the button, both appointments (past and future) are also shown.

I attach both CitaController and the index blade:

CitaController´s code:

```
public function index()
    {


       $citas = Cita::all();
       return view('citas/index',['citas'=>$citas]);

    }
```

index view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Citas</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @include('flash::message')
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.create', 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                        {!!   Form::submit('Crear cita', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.index', 'method'=>'get']) !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <br>

                            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['citas.show','id'], 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                            {!!   Form::submit('todas las citas', ['class'=> 'btn btn-warning'])!!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}

                            <br><br>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Medico</th>
                                <th>Paciente</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Localización</th>
                                <!--<td>Hospital</td>
                                <td>Consulta</td> -->
                                <th>Duración</th>
                                <th>Hora finalización</th>


                                <th colspan="2">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>

                            @foreach ($citas as $cita)


                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->fecha_hora }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->medico->full_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->paciente->full_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->location->hospital}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->location->consulta}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->duracion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->hora_fin}}</td>


                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['citas.edit',$cita->id], 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                                        {!!   Form::submit('Editar', ['class'=> 'btn btn-warning'])!!}
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['citas.destroy',$cita->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                                        {!!   Form::submit('Borrar', ['class'=> 'btn btn-danger' ,'onclick' => 'if(!confirm("¿Está seguro?"))event.preventDefault();'])!!}
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

I appreciate any possible help

Comment: Have you tried `Cita::where('appointment_date', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now())->get()`?

Comment: What i need is to recieve a query from the request

Comment: `@foreach ($citas as $cita)` change to `@foreach ($citas->where('appointment_date', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now()) as $cita)`. This queries your collection and returns only upcoming appointments, assuming the column for appointment date is `appointment_date`

Comment: And then, how do you show all appointments? Both past and future appointments

Comment: Same as you did before. If you want to show all/past/future appointments in a single table and only the result switches (table scopes) I recommend using [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Hey ! I really appreciate your help. I´ve done a similar function to filter the patients by the doctor´s specialty.
Here i attach the code used:

Comment: public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $especialidades= Especialidad::all()->pluck('name','id');
        $especialidad_id=$request->get('especialidad_id');
        $query_base = Paciente::orderBy('id', 'desc');
        if(isset($especialidad_id) && $especialidad_id!=""){
            $query_base->where('especialidad_id',$especialidad_id);
        }
        $pacientes = $query_base->paginate(6);
        return view('pacientes/index',compact('pacientes'),['especialidades'=>$especialidades])->withUsers($pacientes);
    }

Comment: Is there any way to do something similar, but with appointments and the date of the appointments? So in the index, only future are shown but there is a button that shows all appointments.

Answer (score 0):

Possible (but somewhat ugly solution)

This will show future appointments by default and all Appointments after the button click

blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Citas</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @include('flash::message')
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.create', 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                        {!!   Form::submit('Crear cita', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'citas.index', 'method'=>'get']) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('data', 'all') !!}
                        {!! Form::submit('Show cita', ['class'=> 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <br>

                            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['citas.show','id'], 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                            {!!   Form::submit('todas las citas', ['class'=> 'btn btn-warning'])!!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}

                            <br><br>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Medico</th>
                                <th>Paciente</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Localización</th>
                                <!--<td>Hospital</td>
                                <td>Consulta</td> -->
                                <th>Duración</th>
                                <th>Hora finalización</th>


                                <th colspan="2">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>

                            @foreach ($citas as $cita)


                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->fecha_hora }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->medico->full_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->paciente->full_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->location->hospital}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->location->consulta}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->duracion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $cita->hora_fin}}</td>


                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['citas.edit',$cita->id], 'method' => 'get']) !!}
                                        {!!   Form::submit('Editar', ['class'=> 'btn btn-warning'])!!}
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['citas.destroy',$cita->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                                        {!!   Form::submit('Borrar', ['class'=> 'btn btn-danger' ,'onclick' => 'if(!confirm("¿Está seguro?"))event.preventDefault();'])!!}
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

controller

```
public function index()
{
    if(isset(request()->input('data')) {
       $citas = Cita::all();
           } else {
       $citas= Cita::where('appointment_date', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now())->get();
    }
    return view('citas/index',['citas'=>$citas]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn´t seem to work either i don´t know why. I´ve declared in my class 'Cita', "fecha_hora" as protected $dates and I ´ve written this in the controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $citas = Cita::all();
        if($request->input('citas')) {
        $citas= Cita::where(Carbon::parse('fecha_hora'), '>', Carbon\Carbon::now())->get();
    }
        //protected $ date
        return view('citas/index',['citas'=>$citas]);

        //$citas = Cita::all();
        //return view('citas/index',['citas'=>$citas]);

    }
```

Comment: But still nothing, it shows me both past and future appointments in the default index view, and when i click the button it shows me the same and what i  want is to have only future appointment as a default view, and when you click on the button you have all the appointments (both future and past appointments).